# How to load pcd pointcloud into librviz RenderPanel?

Tags: ros, pcd, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a librviz instance running in a qt window thanks to http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html.  I would assume I use http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros to convert the loaded pcd data into a PointCloud2, but then how do I add that to the `rviz::VisualizationManager`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225392/how-to-load-pcd-pointcloud-into-librviz-renderpanel?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the answer is in http://answers.ros.org/question/191721/librviz-display-sensor_msgslaserscan/ -  I need to set the PointCloud2 Display to subscribe to a topic, then publish to that topic with the pcd converted into a ros message.

Having the same node publish and subscribe to itself within an rqt plugin, while keeping namespaces distinct from potential other instances of the same node requires a few more details, I chose to use the private node handle:

```
std::string name = "my_point_cloud";
std::string topic = getPrivateNodeHandle() + "/" + name;
rviz::Display*display = manager->createDisplay("rviz/PointCloud2", QString::fromStdString(name), true);
pub = getPrivateNodeHandle().advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal> >(name, 1);
display->subProp("Topic")->setValue(QString::fromStdString(topic));
```

I was hoping that I could get data directly into the custom rviz window without publishing or subscribing... it would be nice to have access controls and permissions on topics, or mark them hidden.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-01**:
You could probably do something similar by writing a new display type; mostly based on the existing PointCloud2 display but with the changes you need.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-01**:
I did try out `processMessage()` but it is protected, it may be as simple as having a subclass with a public method to access that.